# Cassandra for storing click logs

Tags: cassandra, distributed-computing, nosql

I work in ad tech and our current infrastructure uses MySQL for storing clicks and conversion logs. So far, MySQL has been useful to us for running ad hoc queries against click data.
We are considering switching to Cassandra as we receive huge traffic spikes during peak times. Not only that, we are growing at a very fast rate and we get about 500-1000 clicks per second every now and then(for an extended duration,sometimes for 20-30 minutes).
I have been the options available, and so far, my research has let me to believe that nothing beats Cassandra in terms of write performance.
I'm currently in the process of creating a data model to store clicks.
The major component of any clicks are as follows:

1. Campaign id
2. Pub id
3. Timestamp
4. Creative id
5. Event code (whether it is a valid click or an invalid click.This is an int value. For example, event_code=0 is a valid click)

Now, I need to support the following queries:

```
 1. SELECT * FROM clicks WHERE campaign_id=?
 2. SELECT * FROM clicks WHERE campaign_id=? AND date_time>=? AND date_time <=? 
 3. SELECT * FROM clicks WHERE campaign_id=? AND pub_id=? AND  AND date_time>=? AND date_time <=?  AND event_code=?
```

etc
This is simple enough to do with MySQL, after which I just get all the data from these queries in a CSV file.
However, if I were to model my tables based on the first query, this would mean that I would require to create a table in Cassandra like the following:

```
    CREATE TABLE clicks_by_campaign(
     camp_id int,
     pub_id int,
     date_time timestamp,
     creative_id int,
     event_code int,
    //other fields like ip, user agent ,device etc,
    PRIMARY KEY(camp_id,pub_id,date_time,event_code,creative_id))
```

But there are campaigns that can have millions of rows. For example, we have campaigns with a particular id, say id=3, that have more than 7 million clicks.
Wouldn't this create a wide rows problem?  From what I understand, all of this campaign data would be stored as one partition on one physical machine. Is my thinking here correct or am I missing something? Please note that other queries have to be supported as well. For example, I might have to share the click logs for a particular publisher(irrespective of the campaign id). In which case, the query would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM clicks_by_publisher WHERE pub_id=?
```

This obviously would mean that I would have to create another table by the name 'clicks_by_publisher' etc.

I would also like to point out that I would be using Apache Flink that would analyze, aggregate and group clicks info on a time window of 1 minute. These results will further be stored into MySQL to provide as much support for ad-hoc queries as possible.

Can someone point me out in the right direction.
Is there any other strategy that I can use? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options. Three that i feel i can describe. The first is specifying the columns as follows

```
campaign_id = PRIMARY_KEY
event_code = CLUSTER_KEY
date_time = CLUSTER_KEY
```

Running greater than or equal queries on cluster keys is possible. Your queries will run.

You're right in saying this would create a single partition for each campaign id. To solve your rows being stored on one physical machine you could create a different table that links campaign ids to row ids in your clicks table. This would reduce the overall data stored on a single machine.

Another solution would be to prefix each campaign id with a machine id. That splits the number of rows between each machine equally. It would mean creating a query prefixed with each machine id for each query but allows for growth.

This leads onto [spark](https://academy.datastax.com/resources/getting-started-apache-spark-and-cassandra). Spark will handle running your query on multiple machines and concatenating the results for you automatically, essentially doing what i described above without the development overhead.

Working with Cassandra myself, i opted for a combination of the first and second solution because it fit with the data structure i was working with. Remember that Cassandra is very efficient at writes so don't be too conservative about creating tables to help filter queries and more sparsely store your data.

Perhaps storing clicks by a hash of campaign id's prefixed by the date will work for you.
Edit : Unless disabled, Cassandra will automatically hash your primary keys using the Murmur3 algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

To model your requirement for fast reads and distributed right, use below table definition -

```
CREATE TABLE clicks_by_campaign(
 camp_id int,
 createdon bigint,
 pub_id int,
 creative_id int,
 event_code int,
//other fields like ip, user agent ,device etc,
PRIMARY KEY((camp_id,createdon),event_code))
```

This will help to distribute data evenly across the partitions. This will also solves our second and third query -

```
2. SELECT * FROM clicks WHERE campaign_id=? AND date_time>=? AND date_time <=? 
  Query will be - 
 SELECT * FROM clicks_by_campaign WHERE token(camp_id, createdon) > token(100, '1111111111111') AND token(camp_id, createdon) <= token(100, '22222222222222')


 3. SELECT * FROM clicks WHERE campaign_id=? AND pub_id=? AND  AND date_time>=? AND date_time <=?  AND event_code=?
 The query will be - 
SELECT * FROM clicks_by_campaign WHERE token(camp_id, createdon) > token(100, '1111111111111') AND token(camp_id, createdon) <= token(100, '22222222222222') AND event_code=10
```

First query -

```
1. SELECT * FROM clicks WHERE campaign_id=?
```

This is really a anti pattern in cassandra. What I would do , process campaign data batch wise, hourly- daily - weekly - yearly. Think about campaign id again, do we have to process the all the data at a time. Same goes for the 'clicks_by_publisher' .

Edit 1

```
Could you elaborate on what you mean by 'token' ?
```

Cassandra partitions rows using partition key. In above table definition we have combined camp_id and  createdon values (camp_id and createdon think like composit primary key in RDBMS) to form a partition key. The cassandra partitioner  calculates hash value combining camp_id and createdon , and decides which partition the row goes. To retrieve same row, partitioner need to recalculate the hash value. The function toke(), does that.

The time stamp represent the time at click event happened, this value is in milliseconds. Using createdon (type long), will help to evenly distribute the rows across the partitions.

For example for insert statement

```
1. INSERT INTO clicks_by_campaign (camp_id,createdon ,....) values 100,1111111111111,......) the calculated hash, lets say 111 (combining values 100,1111111111111 )  -- this will go in partition 1 
2. INSERT INTO clicks_by_campaign (camp_id,createdon ,....) values (100,2222222222222,......) the calculated hash, lets say 222 (combining values 100,2222222222222 )   -- this will go in partition 2
```

Java has API to convert a date in to milliseconds. Date represented in milliseconds can be converted to any format using any time zone.

In fact , your use case is right candidate to design a time series data model.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you elaborate on what you mean by 'token' ? Moreover, seems to me that you are suggesting to partition campaign data by timestamp(so if we get 5 clicks for 1 timestamp, that would constitute a partition with 5 rows) . That is infact the best way to do it, but I can't imagine running 60 * 60 * 24 queries if I want to fetch click details for a campaign on a particular day.

Comment: @Ankush92 Added few more details to answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'll think more on this. Really appreciate it !

Comment: Instead of timestamp as column name used createdOn , that makes more sense.